# Looking to simplify my jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a page where I am creating multiple buttons that change the html of another area when you click on them. An example of a chunk of jquery shows what I am trying to say.

```
$( "#bbone" ).click(function() {

$('#a').html( '<span>This is a first sample 1<\/span>' );
$('#b').html( '<span>This is a second sample 1<\/span>' );
$('#c').html( '<span>This is a third sample 1<\/span>' );

});
```

I also have a jsfiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/baxj2h49/3/

I just know there is a better way to write this but considering that all of the html for each can be different. I do not see how. Any push in the right direction would be helpful

Comment: is not very clear what you mean. I guess you want to reuse code to make it more scalable, but we lack information to diagnose what can be

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  The code shown in the question is pretty clear and concise, what do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: In my jsfiddle it shows how I have to keep making click functions. So if I have 99 options I have to copy that same four lines of code 99 times. Unless my option is the best way...which would make me happy as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sufficient information from the OP (extensibility, purpose and etc), and without further information about which part of the replaced content should be static or dynamic, my answer only aims to replicate the behavior **as observed** in OP's original fiddle.

If the only difference is the number that comes at the end of each string, you can simply store that number in a HTML5 `data-` attribute, and use a universal click event. The markup can be updated as follow:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="button"><</div>
    <div class="third">
        <ul class="bbul">
        <li id="bbone" data-value="1">ONE</li>
        <li id="bbtwo" data-value="2">TWO</li>
        <li id="bbthree" data-value="3">THREE</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="doub">
        <div id="a"><span>This is a first sample</span> <span class="value"></span></div>
        <div id="b"><span>This is a second sample</span> <span class="value"></span></div>
        <div id="c"><span>This is a third sample</span> <span class="value"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I have inserted an empty span where the numerical value can be inserted without updating the entire content of the `<span>` element.

For your jQuery, it can be simplified into 3 lines:

```
$('.bbul li').click(function() {
    $('.doub div .value').html($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/baxj2h49/4/

Comment: That is dummy data. So they html could be anything really.

Comment: @user3174713 That's why I said we require **further clarification**. Your example is extremely simplified, and you didn't make clear what content should remain static and what should be dynamic.

Comment: You are right. So the info inside the .html() is not going to be static.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate the time guys. I am always too long winded with my coding is all and I am always seeking ways to write less and do more. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i kinda make amendments in the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mdhilwan/baxj2h49/5/

```
$( ".bbul li" ).click(function() {
     $( ".third" ).fadeTo( "fast" , 0.1, function() {});
     $( ".doub" ).fadeTo( "fast" , 1, function() {});
     $( ".button" ).fadeTo( "fast" , 1, function() {});

     var val = $(this).attr("val");
     $("#a").html("<span>This is a first sample " + val + "</span>");
     $("#b").html("<span>This is a second sample " + val + "</span>");
     $("#c").html("<span>This is a third sample " + val + "</span>");
});
```

Basically using an attr val and pulling that out on click